# Feeling uneasy at 90-100 BPM and it takes time to lower it down

Tags: workout, upper-body-workout, heart-rate, recovery-heart-rate

I've a sedentary life style, however, I'm trying to be more active recently.

Whenever I do any activity with moderate intensity e.g. trimming plants, going up/down stairs, running even for a 200m or do any activity which involve my upper body my heart rate (bpm) goes upto 120-130, that might be normal. It then takes a few minutes to go down to 90bpm (while resting), but then it stays there relatively for a longer time (i.e. 1hr+) and during this time I consistently feel uneasy (**symptom:** dry throat, harder to fully breath, light-headness, muscle tension in upper chest where it meets the throat).

A few times I also tried to finish "7 Minute Workout" but my heart rate got high, I felt very uneasy and stopped it.

**My question is**, should not the BPM get down to 65-75bpm (my resting heart rate) from 90bpm relatively faster? and further, is it normal to feel uneasy (especially the provided symptoms) at 90-100bpm (while resting)? If not then what could be the issue?